# SugarCRM gem documentation API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, crm, sugarcrm

I am trying to create a new account using SugarCRM ruby gem,
but the Documentations don't say how I can create it: https://github.com/chicks/sugarcrm

Can you suggest me the way do to that and where I can get API doc for SugarCRM gem ?

thanks
Alessandro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = SugarCRM::Account.new
a.name = 'New Account'
# make sure it's valid
a.valid?
# show errors, if there are any
a.errors
# once the account has no more errors, save it
a.save!
```

You can find more info here:

- basic gem use: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/03/ruby-gem-for-sugarcrm-the-basics/
- advanced gem use: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/04/ruby-gem-for-sugarcrm-ruby-on-rails-integration/
- using the gem with Rails: http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/04/05/ruby-gem-for-sugarcrm-advanced-use/

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask them on GitHub (we'll see them faster): https://github.com/chicks/sugarcrm/issues